# React Component Testing - `useClient` must be used within `WagmiConfig`

Tags: typescript, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library

Next.js app/TypeScript, Jest/React testing library. I would like to test my component but when I render it in a test case, I get the following error.

```
`useClient` must be used within `WagmiConfig`.

Read more: https://wagmi.sh/docs/WagmiConfig

  34 |   const [isValidPath, setIsValidPath] = React.useState(false);
  35 |
> 36 |   const { address } = useAccount();
     |                                 ^
  37 |
  38 |   const [currentConnectedAddress, setcurrentConnectedAddress] = useState("");
  39 |
```

useAccount hook comes from "wagmi" library. This library has a Config component(WagmiConfig). That  wraps child components in _app.tsx. How can I fix this error? I tried to render _app.tsx first again but that is giving error also.

_app.tsx

```
const MyApp = ({
  Component,
  pageProps,
}: AppProps) => {

  const client = new QueryClient();
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-row ">
      <StoreProvider store={store}>
        <SessionProvider session={pageProps?.session} refetchInterval={0}>
          <QueryClientProvider client={client}>
            *<WagmiConfig client={_client}>*
              <MarketProvider>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
                <ToastContainer
                  position="top-right"
                  autoClose={1500}
                  hideProgressBar={true}
                  newestOnTop={false}
                  closeOnClick
                  rtl={false}
                  pauseOnFocusLoss={false}
                  draggable
                  pauseOnHover={false}
                />
                {/* <ReactQueryDevtools /> */}
              </MarketProvider>
            </WagmiConfig>
          </QueryClientProvider>
        </SessionProvider>
      </StoreProvider>
    </div>
  );
```

}

Comment: You have to wrap the component you're rendering in the test with the `WagmiConfig` provider as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap whole App component in index.js :

```
< WagmiConfig >
    <...other component/> 
    <App/>
<WagmiConfig/>
```

It helped me.